# fminsearch syntax in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was going through this code in Matlab. Can someone explain the syntax part of line 4 (fminsearch)-what does the [] signify.

```
function [v_opt]=optdc_fv(Data,dt,x,f,v0)
v_opt=zeros(length(f),1); 
for i=1:length(f)
v_opt(i)=fminsearch(@costf_fv, v0(i), [], Data, dt, x, f(i)); 
end
```

Here costf_fv is the cost function

```
function cf=costf_fv(v, Data, dt, x, fi)
[N, Ch]=size(Data); % No. of data, No. of channel
t=[0:dt:(N-1)*dt]';
lamda=v./fi; %  edited part
%  Discrete Time Fourier Transform in time domain
[xx, tt]=meshgrid(x,t);
j=sqrt(-1);
tmp1=exp(-j*2*pi*fi*tt);
tmp2=Data.*tmp1; 
Ui=sum(tmp2); 
% Discrete Space Fourier transform --> velocity domain
tmp1=exp(j*2*pi/lamda*x'); 
tmp2=Ui.*tmp1; 
UUi=sum(tmp2); 
cf=-(abs(UUi)); % f-v Spectrum : edited part
```

Comment: it looks like the code you have passes an empty matrix [] into the first input of costf_fv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests with the `fminsearch`-function and it turns out, that the value `[]` is just a placeholder, instead of writing an arbitrary number. If you call...

```
fminsearch(@costf_fv, v0(i), [], Data, dt, x, f(i));
```

... then `@costf_fv` is the function handle and `v0(i)` is the starting point. The following five arguments are the arguments for your function `cost_fv`.

The algorithm behind `fminsearch` adjusts a specific value of your function in every iteration. This value is **the first argument** of `cost_fv` and is exactly at the position of `[]`.

No matter what value you provide instead of `[]`, it will be overwritten (even in the first iteration) by `fminsearch`. Therefore it is replaced by `[]` to show explicitly that there is no need to provide the value yourself.